# CEWP and Script editor webparts missing in our SharePoint Online Tenant

Tags: cewp, script-webpart, spo

CEWP and Script editor webparts are missing in our SharePoint Online sites.

Custom Scripts is allowed for self created sites but prevented only for personal sites. This I checked in SharePoint Online Admin Center --> Settings --> Custom Scripts.

Also in Web part gallery of everysite collection, i am able to see MSContentEditor.dwp and MSScriptEditor.webpart.

Why is the CEWP and Script editor webpart still not available?

Answer (score 0):

The legacy Script Editor and Content Editor WebParts are not available in the Modern Experience of SharePoint Online. You can however continue to use them in sites using the Classic Experience.

To use similar functionality in modern sites, have a look at [a replacement for the WebParts that is using the SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor). There are a lot more samples for modern WebParts [in the official GitHub repository](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts).

This [Medium article](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4) describes one of the ways to adapt the sample solution.